# Creating parent nodes from child nodes when importing from CSV in Drupal6

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, import

I'm working on a Drupal project where I have two types of nodes built with CCK content types --  "venues" (parent nodes) and "concerts" (child nodes).

I've imported a bunch of well-known venues from CSV via node_import module, and now need to import another CSV filled with shows.

How do I:

a. Reference the venues from the concerts CSV -- what I essentially need to do is create a nodereference based on a location.module address (But not the CCK type because of how I imported the venues), but I don't know how to import like this, especially when the same address may vary somewhat between the two sheets (in terms of punctuation, etc.).

b. For some concert listings, it's likely my venue datasheet will be incomplete. When importing, how do I create parent nodes when the importer can't find the address referenced by the child node? Note that the concerts CSV has most of the information from the venues CSV in each row.

I mention I'm using node_import but am thinking I may need to use the Data API for this. I have no experience with the latter (Or preference for a particular importing method, really) and would be grateful for any help whatsoever you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

feeds will be a good solution for you, I think. You'll need to set it up with importers for the 2 different content types, and depending on how your files are structured you may need to run the same file though both importers.

For the node reference you'll either need to use the node_reference mapper that may only exist as a patch at this time, or write your own (which we ended up doing in an afternoon).

We are currently doing something simular importing 60k auction listings and spread across 30-40 Events. Works like a charm.

node reference mapper:
http://drupal.org/node/724536

feeds:
http://drupal.org/project/feeds

Regarding why you may need to import the same file more than once, here is a simplified example of how we import a csv file that has info about items and events in the same file. 
if you have a file that has the following structure:

```
|item_id|event_id|item_body  |event_body  |

|12231  | 123    | 'price $1'| 'on friday'|

|12232  | 123    | 'price $5'| 'on friday'|
```

we run this for both an event content type importer, for both the *_id column is the GUID, and the body is imported as the body. The event importer runs first. For the item the event_id is used to find the node that was created for the event, and a node reference is created. The info for the content type that is not being imported gets ignored.

Only the first instance of the event_id needs the body or other fields, but some of our providers duplicate the data which doesn't actually slow things down, from what i remember. We also have providers that send 2 seperate files 1 for events and one for items, with the items containing a column for event id.

Comment: That's useful; I'll give that a shot later this afternoon and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain the line "depending on how your files are structured you may need to run the same file through both importers" a bit more, please? Thanks!

Comment: updated the answer, since formatting was easier there. Let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: I *think* I'm picking up what you're putting down... What does the GUID do? Is it just a DB key column? Apologies if that's a totally n00b question, I haven't done a ton of Drupal DB stuff. Also, doing a one-to-many relationship using unique keys might be difficult due to variances in address formatting -- these databases were created by two different people and so there are differences in formatting, I.e., NW versus N.W. versus nw. Any idea how I'd get around this without manually going through these DBs and assigning numerical IDs to each venue?

Comment: GUID is best described as the "unique incoming key" for an import to work correctly it would really need to be unique for each venue. in your import files you would need some type of venue id for my approach to really work, and both the events and the venu would need to have corresponding ids.

Comment: If your data isn't consistent another option would be to import and then use create some VBO views that make linking the events and venues easy-ish. Depending on how many you have that may be a better interface than a spreadsheet. http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations

Comment: I'll check that out. I might try using Google Refine to sanitize my data a bit and then re-import. Thanks!